# xml error:System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: Expression must evaluate to a node-set

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to find a node in my xml file but getting the error ( see title)?

```
 // instantiate XmlDocument and load XML from file
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"C:\temp\test2.xml");
        var  node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Offers/Offer/ID=[text()='1']");
        var test = node;
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Offers>
  <Offer>
    <Model>AAAA</Model>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>First offer</Name>
  </Offer>
  <Offer>
    <Model>BBBB</Model>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>Second offer</Name>
  </Offer>
  </Offers>
```

Comment: It's a pretty poor error message because your XPath expression is syntactically invalid, it should be a syntax error not a type error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `=` after ID:

```
 var  node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Offers/Offer/ID=[text()='1']");
```

becomes:

```
 var  node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Offers/Offer/ID[text()='1']");
```

Comment: ok if I want to change the Name node in here how to do that? by using the ID key

Comment: `doc.SelectSingleNode("/Offers/Offer/ID[text()='1']").NextSibling.InnerText = "new text";` - should do the job.

Comment: `doc.SelectSingleNode("/Offers/Offer/ID[text()='1']").ParentNode.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText = "new text";`